# Scala: Take List[People] and Convert it to a Map[String, List[People]]

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections

I'm very new to Scala and am trying to figure out how to work with Collections. If I have a List[People], all of whom have names, is there a way to turn this into a Map[Person.getName, List[People]].

I tried

```
list map (t => t.getName() -> t) toMap,
```

but that only returns a Map[Name, People]. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`groupBy` will take a `List[People]` and transfrom it to a `Map[String, List[People]]` based on the "discriminator function" you provide which in this case is to select the name from `Person`.

```
scala> case class Person(name: String, age:Int)
defined class Person

scala> val people = List(Person("Alice", 42), Person("Bob", 42))
people: List[Person] = List(Person(Alice,42), Person(Bob,42))

scala> people.groupBy(p => p.name)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Person]] = Map(Bob -> List(Person(Bob,42)), Alice -> List(Person(Alice,42)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it yourself and learn how it works, you can try this:

```
scala> case class Person(name: String, surname: String, age:Int)
defined class Person

scala> val people = List(Person("Alice", "Wonderland", 42), Person("Bob", "Father", 42), Person("Bob", "Son", 20))
people: List[Person] = List(Person(Alice,Wonderland,42), Person(Bob,Father,42), Person(Bob,Son,20))

scala> val names = people.map(_.name).distinct
names: List[String] = List(Alice, Bob)

scala> names.map(n => n -> people.filter(_.name == n)).toMap
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Person]] = Map(Alice -> List(Person(Alice,Wonderland,42)), Bob -> List(Person(Bob,Father,42), Person(Bob,Son,20)))
```

Cheers

Comment: That's a really slow way of doing it. O(N^2), for the second `map`.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul, yeah, wasn't considering performance, just an alternative way of manipulating info that might helped the op to reason about it. groupBy is definitely more concise and efficient. Cheers